# Can I switch off long-exposure noise reduction on my Canon SX530?

Tags: canon, long-exposure, noise-reduction

I've been experimenting a bit with some long exposure shots on a Canon SX530 HS, and have noticed that it takes twice as long as the exposure time to actually shoot anything (2 seconds taking, 2 seconds "busy"). I'm led to believe that this is taking a 'dark frame' for some kind of long-exposure noise reduction - however I wanted to try photographing a fireworks display, and so would really like to not have that dead time in between shots, so I'd like to disable this feature. When I look through the settings, though, I can't find anything relevant.

Is there any way I can turn this noise reduction feature off on this model of camera, or am I stuck with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the note on page 74 of the *PowerShot SX530 HS User Guide* and absent of any instructions as to how to disable it, I would say there is no way to disable this using the official Canon firmware.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's a shame that this is the case. However, I managed to find a test build of CHDK that actually does the trick (switching 'dark frame subtraction' off), but am a bit wary of actually recommending it as it's not 'official' by any standards and I've only used it for five minutes so far. So I'll accept your answer and just leave this note about CHDK in the footnotes.